# What am I? -- I'm a tree. Dead. Then floating free

Tags: riddle

I'm a tree.

Dead. Then floating free.

Mix, mash, and grind.

Under the sun.

By Lun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surely you must be

> Paper.

The first four lines describe

> the process of making paper: felling trees, pulping them, and after a couple of other steps, finally drying the paper

And the last line refers to

> [Cai Lun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cai_Lun), who's often credited as the inventor of paper.